# on updating case in test class, trigger.new has the same value as trigger.oldmap even after update

Tags: unit-test

I have written a test class to cover logic written on before update trigger. The test class is failing at the assert step and upon checking i found that OwnerId in both trigger.new and trigger.oldmap are same even when i am updating it. Below is the code, request you yo kindly help me find the issue.

Method of handler class called from trigger:

```
public static void wmgRemoveOldGroupQueue(Map<Id,Case> newMap, Map<Id,Case> oldMap){
        String wmgRecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get('WMG_Operations_Workflow').getRecordTypeId();
        for (Case o : newMap.values()) {
            if (o.RecordTypeId == wmgRecordTypeId && !((String)o.OwnerId).startsWith('005') 
                && (o.OwnerId != oldMap.get(o.Id).OwnerId)) {
                newMap.get(o.Id).ANN_Accepted_From_Queue__c = '';
            }
        }
    }
```

Test class:

```
static testMethod void wmgRemoveOldQueueTest() {

    //setup 
    User thisUser = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Id = :UserInfo.getUserId()]; 
    String wmgRecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get('WMG_Operations_Workflow').getRecordTypeId();
    String assertMsg = 'Accepted From Queue did not clear out';
    Group q = new Group();
    q.Name = 'WMG Test';
    q.Type = 'Queue';
    insert q;

    QueueSObject qSobj = new QueueSObject();
    qSobj.QueueId = q.Id;
    qSobj.SobjectType = 'Case';
    System.runAs(thisUser){
        insert qSobj;
    }

    Case c = new Case();
    c.OwnerId = thisUser.Id;
    c.RecordTypeId = wmgRecordTypeId;
    c.ANN_Accepted_From_Queue__c = 'WMG Test';
    insert c; 
    c = [SELECT Id, OwnerId FROM Case WHERE Id =: c.Id];
    Test.startTest();
    c.OwnerId = q.Id;
    update c;
    Test.stopTest();

    c = [SELECT Id, OwnerId, ANN_Accepted_From_Queue__c FROM Case WHERE Id =: c.Id];
    System.assertEquals(null, c.ANN_Accepted_From_Queue__c, assertMsg);
} // -- failing at this step
```

Comment: Nice first question! After staring at your code for a bit, I don't see anything obviously wrong. I think your issue might lie elsewhere. Seeing how `wmgRemoveOldGroupQueue()` is called by your trigger might help. How are you determining that the ownerId in `trigger.new` and `trigger.oldMap` are the same?

Comment: Pro tip: Instead of `(String)o.OwnerId).startsWith('005') `; use `o.OwnerId.getSobjectType() == User.SobjectType`

Comment: `newMap.get(o.Id).ANN_Accepted_From_Queue__c = '';` but you assert `System.assertEquals(null, c.ANN_Accepted_From_Queue__c, assertMsg);`  empty string is not same as null

Comment: @cropredy, +1 I think what you said is the actual answer

Answer (score 2):

I note in your code that you set:

```
newMap.get(o.Id).ANN_Accepted_From_Queue__c = '';  // empty string
```

But in your testmethod you:

```
c = [SELECT Id, OwnerId, ANN_Accepted_From_Queue__c FROM Case WHERE Id =: c.Id];
System.assertEquals(null, c.ANN_Accepted_From_Queue__c, assertMsg);  // null
```

Empty string is not the same as null so the assert fails

I recommend that your PROD code do this instead:

```
newMap.get(o.Id).ANN_Accepted_From_Queue__c = null;  // don't use empty string
```

**N.B.**
this is not the clearest to someone not *au fait* with key prefixes:

```
(String)o.OwnerId).startsWith('005')
```

instead, use

```
o.OwnerId.getSobjectType() == User.SobjectType
```

Comment: Hi, 
Actually, c.ANN_Accepted_From_Queue__c has the queue name and not empty string or null value. Also, i tried matching the SobjectType of owner with user object but no luck.

Comment: I had used system.debug in the handler class method with which i could see that o.OwnerId and oldmap had the same value i.e. newmap also has previous value only and not updated value for ownerId.

Comment: `c.OwnerId = q.Id;    update c;` - in the before update trigger the value of `c.ownerid` is not `q.Id` ?  Do you have other triggers on Case that might be firing in an unexpected order?

Comment: Yes, its not q.Id but rather thisuser.id

Comment: There are other triggers running amd i also tried inactivating all the before update and after insert triggers but even then same issue